How do Christians respond to leaders closing down borders?
Jesus taught the message of love when he told the disciples to let the kids come to him for to such innocent children and child-like people the kingdom of God is theirs.
Jesus was a man known to hang out with people society deemed bad like;

The woman caught in adultery
Zachaeus the Tax collector
He was crucified in the midst of two thieves
Tolerated Julius's lies, stealing, and other sins even as it directly harmed His mission and His disciples.

Does His example require us and all we love to risk increase crime, sickness, poverty, homelessness, further loss of our once Trusting society, neighbors that hate our society, resent and hate us, cripple public services, drive down wages, .., for the vane disOrdered unJust unTrue destructive false display of virtue?
So, when a ruler like Trump gives out an order to build a wall, is he acting out of prudence, in Protecting and Providing for the Nation as in a father-like Duty, or with a similar spirit that incited the disciples to prevent the kids from coming onto Jesus?
How would Jesus guide President Trump in this issue once he takes Office?
Jesus sought to welcome people from all walks of life, because he loved everyone, would He shun from erecting structures such as walls that 'seem to' divide rather than unite people?



little kids
immigrants




The disciples tried to block their access to Jesus physically
leaders block their access to America by ordering a wall constructed



Provide biblical references and-or any Chrisian sect's Doctrines that best supports what is the correct response to our open-boarder situation as it stands today.

Personally, I voted for the Socialist party  :) I’d never vote for Trump or join the veritable cult worship they got going on with him. That said, I also refused to vote for Kamala as she had no meaningful platform to support. I’d love to see Bernie run again, though by the time the next election rolls around he may not be fit enough for it due to his age. I think AOC will one day stand a shot at the office

My kingdom is no part of this world

@RyanPierceWilliams I think we should keep political statements like that outta here, it will just get messy  cause someone like me will say something like "socialism is theft".

Except for scale, how is enforcing a country's border significantly different from locking the door on your own home? Or are all strangers welcome to enter whenever they want?

@Wyrsa you are welcome to make such statements. You’d be wrong, but feel free. And then maybe attempt to explain why “taxes” are theft, but “tithe” in the OT Law is good and holy. Or how about the straight up forgiveness of all debts every 7 years?

@RyanPierceWilliams We do not have the right to force others to work for us (Slavery). We do not have the right to force others to give us their property (Theft). We do not have the right to force others to pay our bills (Theft). It is also plagued by the problems of Monopoly (Greed, Corruption).
Let us care for those in need, but let us do that voluntarily. The only people who have a right to our labor or property are our own children, when they are too young to care for themselves.
Tithe is something else. And it would be interesting if debts could work like that today.

@Wyrsa the scriptures clearly disagree with you. Give to God what is God’s and give to Caesar what is Caesar’s.

@Wyrsa says "We do not have the right to … ." — No, we don't. But our government does. Romans 13:1, "Everyone must submit to governing authorities. For all authority comes from God, and those in positions of authority have been placed there by God.", and 1 Peter 12:13–14, "Submit yourselves to every ordinance of man for the Lord's sake: whether it be to the king, as supreme; Or unto governors …".

@Kristopher, it is because Jesus will rule the nations with a rod of iron after he returns for the millenia

I don't believe it is correct to attempt to compare a country with the Messiah.

Regarding the spiritual world
Why did Christ eat with tax collectors, whores, and sinners? While there is a specific passage in the gospel of Mark... the best answer seems to be in Luke 15. With the three parables: The Lost Sheep, the Lost Coin, and the Prodigal Son.
He went to them to help them. Because they needed help, because He was able to offer help, and because it was the right thing to do.

Regarding the earthly world.
This question is ultimately a political matter. A Christian would have to balance the call to care for themselves with the call to care for others who are in need.
When Trump opposes illegal immigration and desires a wall. From a Christian standpoint there is no issue, because protecting the people you are responsible for is a very Christian thing to do. Likewise, if you allowed them all to come and properly cared for them without citizens being harmed, that is also very Christian. But it would be very sinful to welcome people and then not properly care for them and/or the citizens you are responsible for.
It's literally like adopting a child. You cannot neglect your biological children for the new one, you cannot prefer the biological children above the one you adopted. If you can hold immigrants and citizens in stability and harmony. Then that's good.
But it is more than just the immigrants isn't it? It is about the drugs, underage sex slaves, and other black market problems.
Like most political things or actions performed on Earth, it will not meet the high standard of Christianity. Because to meet that standard... well, both countries would be equally desirable places to live.
Ultimately the position of Trump, to secure a border will result in many good things and some bad things. This is sadly how the earthly sinful world works. We cannot implement the ideal solution due to the sins of ourselves or the sins of others. (Like we cannot abolish police or military, because sinful people will hurt defenseless people, even though ideally we shouldn't need police or military and live in harmony)
But the situation of a border at all, is a regrettable situation based on living in world that is filled with sin.

-1 for answering an obviously inappropriate question.

Comment upvoted, for at least explaining. :) Though I think the question is valid. How do christians respond? My answer is they can respond both ways, for or against, the situation is one caused by the sinful world we live in. Just like killing in self defense is a situation caused by the sin of the attacker, that resulted in even more sin. [Adds -1 to salt collection}

"I think the question is valid." But not as worded. "How do Christians …?" is far too general and will generate many different viewpoints.

Which makes my answer the best one... My answer was they can respond along the entire spectrum of the question, all the way from "totally for it" to "totally against" regardless the situation is a tragic one.

The OP is conflating two separate distinct motifs.
At the Great Commission, Jesus tells the disciples to go and make disciples out from all nations.  There is no sense of waiting for people to come into your country before making disciples.  It may, of course, happen that way, but "closing the border" has nothing to do with being a Christian per se.
The leader of a country, or in the case of America, the leaders (president, congress, supreme court) have the duty to follow the laws of the country.  In this case the Constitution Article 4 Section 4 requires this.

Section 4


The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government, and shall protect each of them against Invasion; and on Application of the Legislature, or of the Executive (when the Legislature cannot be convened) against domestic Violence. -source-

Here are specific OP questions and answers.

OP: So when a ruler like Trump gives out an order to build a wall, is he acting out of the same spirit that incited the disciples to prevent the kids from coming onto Jesus?

No.

OP: What would Jesus have done if he was the president of the United States?

He would follow the laws.

OP: It seems as if Jesus sought to welcome people from all walks of life, because he loved everyone, and that he would shun from erecting structures such as walls that seem to divide rather than unite people, how do Christians respond?

While it is true that every person may repent and be saved because God so loved the world, it does not follow that erecting walls or permitting rivers to flow that may divide has any influence on this.
Go and make.

Jesus would surely open the borders to people looking to better themselves out of love.

People may enter the country legally.  There is no sense of Jesus supporting illegal activities.

The old and new testaments do not say we cannot defend ourselves and our country.  Having open borders AND not vetting persons for entrance into our nation, has left us open to a host of problems, including criminal activity.  We are allowing people who do not respect our laws to flood our country and our people suffer for it.
